# Login Without Correct Password...How Do I Fix?

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, password-protection

I am building a Login page for my website. I have used Dreamweaver to create the login code. I don't know a lot about php, **but when I login using an incorrect password (but correct username) it allows me into a restricted part of the site.**

For example: suppose the correct username is test and the correct username is test123. When a user types in "test" for the username and types in any letter (though if you type in a number it doesn't let you through) for the password it logs them in and allows them through. This would be bad...

**Is there a way to make sure the site checks that *both* the password and username are correct?**

I don't know hardly anything about php. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my login code:

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/--------_userdatabase.php');

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = ""){
    if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
    }

    $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

    switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
            break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
            break;
        case "double":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
            break;
        case "date":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
            break;
        case "defined":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
            break;
    }
    return $theValue;
}


// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
    $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
    $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "http://www.-----------.org";
    $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "http://www.-----------.org/login.php";
    $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
    mysql_select_db($database_-------_userdatabase, $--------_userdatabase);

    $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Username, Password FROM userdatabase WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "int"), GetSQLValueString($password, "int")); 

    $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $--------_userdatabase) or die(mysql_error());
    $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
    if ($loginFoundUser) {
        $loginStrGroup = "";

        if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {
            session_regenerate_id(true);
        } else {
            session_regenerate_id();
        }
        //declare two session variables and assign them
        $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
        $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

        if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
            $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];    
        }
        if ($loginUsername === 'Admin') {
            header("Location: http://www.------------.org/user/-------/");
        } else if ($loginUsername === 'User') {
            header("Location: http://www.------------.org/user/-------/");
        } else if ($loginUsername === 'User2') {
            header("Location: http://www.-----------.org/user/--------/");
        } else {
            header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your passwords are in int? Is it that way or do u want to process them as string. Also your if else seems to be buggy. Last else in if-else always redirects to redirectloginsuccess

Comment: Tidied up you syntax above - are these all in the same file or different files? As i think you'd better specify if they are different

Answer (score 1):

You must add `die();` after a `header()` redirect, as `header()` *only* sends a header to the browser, without really knowing what it means. It then continues to serve the content as usual, if you don't have `die()` after it.

## Partial example

```
<?php
if ($loginFoundUser) {
 // Put the cut out code back in
 if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
 }
 if ($loginUsername === 'Admin') {
  header("Location: http://www.------------.org/user/-------/");
  die;
 } else if ($loginUsername === 'User') {
  header("Location: http://www.------------.org/user/-------/");
  die;
 } else if ($loginUsername === 'User2') {
  header("Location: http://www.-----------.org/user/--------/");
  die;
 } else {
  header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  die;
 }
} else {
 header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
 die;
}
?>
```

Also, it appears you're converting the values to INT before checking the values in the database, which should not be done (considering a valid `$loginUsername` is 'Admin'). This can be changed with the following code:

```
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "string"), GetSQLValueString($password, "string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following link the restricted area?

http://www.------------.org/user/-------/

Comment: Yes, it sends the user to their account page which shows their info. There is php code on that page that redirects the user if they are not logged in or are not a certain user so that only one person can view that page.

Comment: In that case this has to be your if statement that is supposed to check both the username and password. I am not sure why you have a database connection when it's not being used.. "if ($loginUsername === 'Admin') {". There is no check for password in that statement which means as long as the user types in Admin, User or User2 they can log in. You want to replace that with "if ($loginUsername == 'Admin' && $password == 'passwordhere') {"

Comment: @umarsa, the credentials are checked with `if ($loginFoundUser) {`, and the user is *supposed* to be redirected to a different page (and therefore should not be able to access the current page) if the credentials do not match. So, `$loginUsername` is only used if the user/pass combination is valid.